# How to handle situation, if the file is being locked by gradle daemon

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

While running an application `processResources` task of gardle(Copies resources from their source to their target directory, potentially processing them) tries to delete the `git.properties` file in build folder,

However, the same file is being created at run time while building an application in some task before `proceeResources`, but getting locked by gradle daemon so the task `proceeResources` can't work on it and  ends with an error,

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: {projectWebappPath}\build\resources\main\git.properties
> Unable to delete file: {projectWebappPath}\build\resources\main\git.properties
```

In SysinternalSuite, if I run the program procExp.exe on windows 7, I can see the file is locked by gradle daemon.

**Question is :-**

How do I handle this situation, I have no clue, I was trying with disabling daemon but it is not recommended. Which didnt resolve issue either.

I have started getting this issue 3 days before, earlier it was working fine, I dont understand what could be the reason and if I try to exclude `processResources` task while building for time being, it has another impacts so cant really do that.

I'm using windows 7,64 bit OS, trying to run `gradlew build` on intellij terminal.

Any help or clue would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

on Windows, this might be something alike:

```
taskkill /F /IM gradlew.bat /T
```

or whatever name the gradle daemon uses there.

you could also kill the stalled instance with the GUI task-manager.

generally, it can only be the last one instance of the daemon, which could have locked the file. also look for `*.lock` files, which might be impossible to delete when building under various user accounts.